# on hover how to show inner absolute position div to outside scrollable div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a fixed width and height `div` with `overflow:auto` property, under this `div` I have one table with multiple `row` and on one `td` i am showing one **div(pop-content)** `onhover` by `fade-In` effect. But when I hovered on last `td` the `div` is showing but comes under the scroll area and create too much blank space in bottom which I don't want.

I want to show the div(pop-content) outside the scrollable area if the row is last or second last without losing scroll property. below is my code

jQuery:-

```
$(function () {
        $(".pop-outer").each(function () {
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).find(".pop-content").stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
            }, function () {
                $(this).find(".pop-content").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
            });
        });
    });
```

Html:-

```
<div class="grid-inner clearfix" style="overflow:auto; height:135px">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="new-grid">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="even-color1" align="left" valign="middle">
                        <div class="pop-outer" style="position:relative">
                            <a href="#">Williams, Josh</a>
                            <div class="pop-content" style="display:none; position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px">
                                <span class="lft-arrow"></span>
                                <div class="pop-img-cont"><img src="Image/candidate1-large.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                <div class="pop-description">
                                    <h3>Josh Williams</h3>
                                    <strong>Boston, MA</strong>
                                    <h4>How Do You Define Success?</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In porttitor ultricies odio ut placerat. Nam molestie consequat est, et sagittis nisl laoreet eu. Integer sodales, odio id malesuada commodo, neque ante faucibus turpis, ut porttitor risus libero sit amet leo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="even-color2" align="left" valign="middle">New York</td>
                    <td class="even-color3" align="left" valign="middle">Goldman Sachs &amp; Co</td>
                    <td class="even-color4" align="left" valign="middle">NYU</td>
                    <td class="even-color5" align="left" valign="middle">06/01/2012</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="even-color1" align="left" valign="middle">
                        <div class="pop-outer" style="position:relative">
                            <a href="#">Williams, Josh</a>
                            <div class="pop-content" style="display:none; position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px">
                                <span class="lft-arrow"></span>
                                <div class="pop-img-cont"><img src="Image/candidate1-large.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                <div class="pop-description">
                                    <h3>Josh Williams</h3>
                                    <strong>Boston, MA</strong>
                                    <h4>How Do You Define Success?</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In porttitor ultricies odio ut placerat. Nam molestie consequat est, et sagittis nisl laoreet eu. Integer sodales, odio id malesuada commodo, neque ante faucibus turpis, ut porttitor risus libero sit amet leo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="even-color2" align="left" valign="middle">New York</td>
                    <td class="even-color3" align="left" valign="middle">Goldman Sachs &amp; Co</td>
                    <td class="even-color4" align="left" valign="middle">NYU</td>
                    <td class="even-color5" align="left" valign="middle">06/01/2012</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="even-color1" align="left" valign="middle">
                        <div class="pop-outer" style="position:relative">
                            <a href="#">Williams, Josh</a>
                            <div class="pop-content" style="display:none; position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px">
                                <span class="lft-arrow"></span>
                                <div class="pop-img-cont"><img src="Image/candidate1-large.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                <div class="pop-description">
                                    <h3>Josh Williams</h3>
                                    <strong>Boston, MA</strong>
                                    <h4>How Do You Define Success?</h4>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In porttitor ultricies odio ut placerat. Nam molestie consequat est, et sagittis nisl laoreet eu. Integer sodales, odio id malesuada commodo, neque ante faucibus turpis, ut porttitor risus libero sit amet leo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="even-color2" align="left" valign="middle">New York</td>
                    <td class="even-color3" align="left" valign="middle">Goldman Sachs &amp; Co</td>
                    <td class="even-color4" align="left" valign="middle">NYU</td>
                    <td class="even-color5" align="left" valign="middle">06/01/2012</td>
                  </tr>


              </table>

          </div>
```

Comment: A fiddle would be useful.

Comment: you need to play with css..set position to absolute and add other css to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
<div class="pop-content" style="display:none;background: #eee;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 10px;border-radius: 8px;box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);position: absolute;width: 200px;">
```

replace it everywhere inside html and try.

Comment: no i already tried this...actually everything is working fine pop-content div is showing but i want if it show on last row then it should not take extra space in bottom....i want to show out of grid-inner div

Answer (score 0):

I give an answer for those who may have the problem.

The only solution is to replace absolute position with a fixed position.
Be careful, you, will have to set coordinate relative to the window (and coordinates could change if you scroll).

The easiest way is to set the left and top position using jQuery in hover functions.
Below is a sample :

```
    $(function () {
        $(".pop-outer").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.hover(function () {
                var offset = $this.offset();
                $this.find(".pop-content")
                    .stop(true, true)
                    .fadeIn(300)
                    .css({
                        'position': 'fixed',
                        'left': offset.left,
                        'top': offset.top
                    });

            }, function () {
                $this.find(".pop-content")
                    .stop(true, true)
                    .fadeOut(300);
            });
        });
    });
```